# How can I get OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider to return a specific Error Code or response when a token is expired (instead of invalid)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

I've got a regular OWIN OAuth setup for my MVC WebAPI project - one of the requests from the frontend developers was to be able to determine whether a token is rejected because it's expired, or when it's just an invalid token.

From what I can tell, by default the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider sits in the middle and magically just intercepts requests looking at the Authorization header for the bearer token, and determines whether to authorize or send a 401 / Authorization has been denied for this request.

Is it possible to customize this behaviour / is there any other way to determine the *reason* behind authorization being denied?

I can see the following method exists:

```
public virtual Task ValidateAuthorizeRequest(OAuthValidateAuthorizeRequestContext context);
```

But I'm not sure what the default implementation is, what it looks like, or whether this is where I'm supposed to go to customize the provider to achieve what I'm after.

My OAuthOptions in Startup.cs:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I came searching for a exactly same problem that you reported here.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(